# backups.backupdb seems empty

Tags: backup, time-machine, snow-leopard, nas

I use a NAS (WD mycloud ex2) to backup my computer with time machine. Usually it works (more or less), but I am dealing now with a quite big issue. Now, I can mount the sparse.bundle file, but afterwards, the backups.backupdb directory seems empty ! I tried to access its content from the finder or with the terminal.

The interface on the NAS keep saying that 400 G0 are occupied in the time machine backup directory. But finder of command line show zero Ko in the backups.backupdb directory.

I can't use the time machine application because I did reinstall my MacBook. However, I used to access the time machine backup directory to copy files, even after the re-installation (so it doesn't seem to be an issue with the re-installation).

Any idea to solve it?